# JQuery datetimepicker()

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I am using date time picker in a form to store a date of a transaction.

In events where I wish to edit a transaction, I note that the field does not show the value of the form in the view.

[image]

When I inspect the view I note that the value attribute has been set.

[image]

What is obviously happening is that when the form loads, the JS is executing:

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
});
```

which clears out the value text.

If I remove id="datetimepicker1" then the value text shows as expected.

Any advice on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply store the value in a variable and then put it back after invoking `datetimepicker`.

```
$(function () {
    var val = $('#datetimepicker1').val();
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
    $('#datetimepicker1').val(val);
});
```